# is there any alternative to set cookie value other than setcookie() in PHP

Tags: php

We tried to set the cookie value in PHP using `setcookie()` but it didn’t set a value. The value to be set in the cookie is `"PHPSESSIONID"`.

We tried to set this value in both HTTP and HTTPS, but couldn’t succeed either way.

Below is the code used to set the cookie value:

```
    var sessionID = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";
    SetCookie(SESSION_COOKIE_ID,sessionID);
```

Where `SESSION_COOKIE_ID` has the value `"PHPSESSIONID"`.

I am calling this function inside javascript tag and HTML head tag.

Comment: can you show the code you are using.

Comment: from what i am reading $_COOKIE['user'] = 'bob' will not set a lasting cookie. Which is odd as that will work for setting session variables

Comment: @JoshuaByer that's because `$_COOKIE[key]` *reads* a cookie by key. `$_SESSION[key]` doesnt change the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

PHPSESSIONID is *usually* a special value used to manage sessions. Sessions are usually managed by [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and friends. Generally, if you’re managing sessions, `session_start()` and its related functions should be the place to look.

However, `setcookie('PHPSESSIONID', $value)` should usually work, though I’d not recommend it (as I said, if you’re using sessions, use the session functions). If it’s not working for you, there must be some other problem.

Remember that cookies (session cookies or otherwise) are in the headers of the document. The functions `header()`, `setcookie()`, and `session_start()` all alike must be called *before any other output*. You cannot output headers *after* content. If you try, you’ll get an error of some kind (which you may or may not see, depending on how you’ve configured your error reporting).

---

That’s as much as I can help you, because

- you have not included any of your code;
- you have not quoted any error messages; nor have you said how your error reporting is configured;
- all you have said is that you “cannot succeed”, which is hopelessly vague as a description of a problem.

Comment: Here is the code I have used to set the cookie.
        var sessionID = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";
        SetCookie(SESSION_COOKIE_ID,sessionID);

Comment: @sreyas. Please edit code into your question. It's much easier to format there (see the code formatting button on the editing toolbar).

Comment: @sreyas. Thanks. I've read your edited question. You are aware that the headers of the document come before *all* content? The `<head>` tag is *part of the content*.

Comment: **TIP:** You can set sessions and cookies *after* output if you use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start)

Comment: @Trig Thanks  for patience in answering my questions.As you said I have added the setcookie()  before <head> tag  but 1st time when session started it didn't work. only for the 2nd session it sets the cookie value. But in our case we need to set this cookie for the first time itself. Could you please tell what might be reason for it.